# how to substitute values to img tag through JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

**I get this response from the AJAX Call made of Jquery**

```
[/Uploaded Files/190420120611171146Wj.jpg, Uploaded Files/IMG4040hY.jpg, /Uploaded Files/a2124.jpg]
```

**This is my JQuery response**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url  : '<%=getChartData%>',
        success : function(data){
                $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                $('img').eq(index).attr('src', item);
             });


        }
    });

});
</script>
```

**This is my div tags with images**

```
<div><a href="#"><img src=""   /></a></div>
<div><a href="#"><img src=""   /></a></div>
<div><a href="#"><img src=""   /></a></div>
<div><a href="#"><img src=""   /></a></div>
```

I tried with the above , but I am not able  to subsitute these values to the images

Updated :

**This is my div container**

```
<div id="fp_thumbContainer">
                <div id="fp_thumbScroller">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="content">
                            <div><a href="#"><img src=""   /></a></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <div><a href="#"><img src=""   />  </a></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <div><a href="#"><img src=""   />  </a></div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: let me ask you this: are these images the only images in your page?

Comment: The images  returned as well as the div img  tags are fixed (10) numbers . i did not show all of them in code above

Answer (score 3):

the problem of using `$('img')` is that it gets ALL images in the page. suppose you have this HTML:

```
<img src="foo" />  <!-- this is eq(0) -->
<img src="foo" />  <!-- this is eq(1) -->
<img src="foo" />  <!-- this is eq(2) -->

<!-- target images -->
<div><a href="#"><img src="" /></a></div>  <!-- this is eq(3) -->
<div><a href="#"><img src="" /></a></div>  <!-- this is eq(4) -->
<div><a href="#"><img src="" /></a></div>  <!-- this is eq(5) -->
```

when you do `$('img')` and you had images before your target images, they are the ones you are replacing and not your actual targets. when you looped through the array, the index starts at `0`. if you had those images before the target images... you know what happens.

---

to make sure you are targetting the right images, make your selector more specific, like `$('div a img')` which is "get all images in an anchor that is in a div" or better, if these target images have a parent, use it as a base instead, like `$('#parent_id img')` which is "get all images in parent container" like:

```
$('#fp_thumbScroller img');  //get all img from fp_thumbscroller
```

---

also, just to add:

- check your urls if they are correct
- check the urls when they are appended to the image if they are correct
- check your ajax call if it returns
- check the return data if it's valid
- check `each` if it does loop

`console.log()` can help you

Comment: i did not get actually what is wrong ?? Shall i place the whole JSP Page ??

Comment: you can check before you do an ajax call what `$('img')` contains by doing `console.log($('img'))`. in the console, you can point at the array values and on the screen, it will highlight the pointed element. if the first 3 of `$('img')` are not the right ones, you might want to be more specific in targetting the images.

Answer (score 0):

@user1253847 if you are getting the image src from server then why not write the whole div html like below..

Make a div wrapper

```
<div id="imagewrapper"></div>
```

and add the div and image into that..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var content = "";
$.ajax({
    url  : '<%=getChartData%>',
    success : function(data){
            $.each(data, function(index, item) {
            content += "<div><a href='#'><img src=" + item + "   /></a></div>";
         });
       $("#imagewrapper").html(content);
    }
  });
});
```

or append like

```
$("#imagewrapper").append(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

add `dataType: "json"` option in your `AJAX` call like follow:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url     : '<%=getChartData%>',
        success : function(data){
                $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                $('#fp_thumbContainer #fp_thumbScroller').find('img').eq(index).attr('src', item);
             });
        }
    });
});
```

even though this its not work then check out JSON response it should be:

```
["\/Uploaded Files\/190420120611171146Wj.jpg","Uploaded Files\/IMG4040hY.jpg","\/Uploaded Files\/a2124.jpg"]
```

For example in php that is something like:

```
<?php
  $arr = array("/Uploaded Files/190420120611171146Wj.jpg", "Uploaded Files/IMG4040hY.jpg", "/Uploaded Files/a2124.jpg");
  echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```